# Select rows from Left table that don't appear on right table on join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I have a mysql problem that I can't find a solution.

I have two tables:

```
groups (group_name, group_id)

members (member_id, group_id, user_id)
```

I want to select all groups that don't have a match for a certain user_id in the members table.

The reason for that is because I want to show to the user all groups that he's not a part of.

If there is also a way to display the number of members in each group (by counting the number of matches in members table) it would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select g.*
from groups g
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from group_members gm
    where gm.group_id = g.group_id and gm.user_id = ?
)
```

The question mark should be replaced with the specific user that you want to use as parameter.

Note that this also brings groups that have no members at all.

If you want the user count per group too, then you can `join` and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select g.group_id, g.group_name, count(gm.group_id) no_members
from groups g
left join group_members gm on gm.group_id = g.group_id
group by g.group_id, g.group_name
having count(gm.user_id) = 0 or max(gm.user_id = ?) = 0
```

Or if you want to evict groups without members:

```
select g.group_id, g.group_name, count(*) no_members
from groups g
inner join group_members gm on gm.group_id = g.group_id
group by g.group_id, g.group_name
having max(gm.user_id = ?) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually there's a problem with the second query. It doesn't show the empty groups. The result ends up being the same as the last one, just showing groups that the user is not a member of and there's at least one member. It's not an actual problem for this specific situation because I won't have any empty groups in my system, but I would like to learn how to do it if I need something like this in the future. But thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: @Jota: I see your point. I modified the second query.